# D3 tree level selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, tree

Could I add a level selector for these trees created with d3.js?

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2966094
or
bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

Add a label on each level to get the level position or expand it.

Added a example picture.

[image: Example]

Comment: The second example would be a better fit: in the first one, there is no guarantee that any level is vertically aligned. In any case, I don't think there is any out-of-the box solutions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the example here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

I would start by nesting the nodes by level:

```
var nodesByLevel = d3.nest().key(function (d) {return d.depth}).entries(nodes);
```

To add your boxes, do something like:

```
svg.selectAll(".levelBox")
  .data(nodesByLevel)
  .enter()            // one box per level
  .append("text")
  .attr("class","levelBox")
  .attr("x", function (d) {return d.values[0].x}) //take the x of the first node in this layer
  .text(function(d) {return d.key}) //the key from the nesting, i.e. the depth      
  .onclick(levelExpand);  // click handler
```

The above is just a skeleton, that should go into the `update` function (you need to take care of the `exit()` and `update()` selections after adding the data, and any additional drawing features).

In `levelExpand`, you have access to the list of nodes for the box that is clicked (in `d.values`). You can then go through the list, expand them, and then update the drawing

```
function levelExpand(d) {
    d.values.forEach(function (n) {n.children = n._children;}); //expand all nodes internally
   update(root); //show the update
}
```